# Gravitational Potential Energy misunderstandings

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

I'm really confused by the derivation of Gravitational Potiential Energy. I took a screenshot of the wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#Work_by_gravity_in_space) below.

My major confusion lies in:
1. The use of the position vector **r** in the Force equation. I'm familiar with -GMm/r^2.  We added a r to the denominator it seems to offset the vector? I'm not sure how to treat this. 
2. Our bounds change from r(t<sub>1</sub>) to r(t<sub>2</sub>) to simply (t<sub>1</sub>) to t<sub>2</sub>. This appears to have something to do with velocity coming into the equation... 
3. In general I don't understand why the PE decreases as height rises toward infinity (which is defined as 0 PE). This would mean that as you raise something up above the earth's surface PE goes down, and PE is higher as you get closer to the center of the earth (becoming infinite as you reach it).

 I know the coordinate system is different than the simplified formula PE=mgh but this still makes no sense to me.

Long post, appreciate any help (or links I should read). Thanks.

[image: Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#Work_by_gravity_in_space]

Comment: Your first equation for force is in error.  The denominator should have an r^2 in it, and the bold "r" at the end of the equation is a vector which is used to indicate the direction of the force.

Comment: @DavidWhite It's accurate. The equation with $r^{-2}$ only calculates the magnitude of the force, disregarding the vector formulation. Really, this equation uses the same $-\frac{GMm}{r^2}$ term, but multiplies it by the unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf{r}$, which is $\mathbf{r}/r$. $\mathbf{R}$ is not a unit vector.

Comment: @HDE226868 , the equation stated by the OP is fairly easy to misinterpret.  The description given by wijay (below) starts the same way, but he ended up with the functional form that I usually see, which isn't easy to misinterpret, because the r-hat designation at the end clearly denotes the unit vector that points between the two objects that are attracting each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) The force law

The force law you give is correct and consistent with the inverse square law. The quantity $\vec{r} /r$ is a vector of unit length that points in the direction of the vector $\vec{r}$. Often unit vector are denoted with "hats," as in $\vec{r} /r = \hat{r}$ Thus, we can write the force law as 
$$ \vec{F} = - \frac{GMm}{r^3}\vec{r} = - \frac{GMm}{r^2}\frac{\vec{r}}{r} = - \frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat{r}. $$
One way to read this equation is words is that gravitational force $\vec{F}$ on mass $m$ from mass $M$ is a vector with magnitude $GMm/r^2$ that points in the direction $-\hat{r}$. This interpretation is sensible for the following three reasons. First, forces are vectors, and the force law should reflect this fact. Second, the vector $-\hat{r}$ points from mass $m$ to mass $M$, so the force is attractive, as a gravitational force should be. Third, the magnitude is the familiar inverse square law.

### 2) Integration Bounds

The point here is the variable of integration changes.The integral is with respect to $r$ when $dr$ appears in the integrand. The integral is with respect to $t$ when $dt$ appears in the integrand. The Wikipedia page for [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) contains an instructive formula:
$$\int _{\varphi (a)}^{\varphi (b)}f(x)\,dx=\int _{a}^{b}f(\varphi (t))\varphi '(t)\,dt.$$
The equation you reference uses precisely this rule.

### 3) Interpretation of the formula for $U(r)$

The minus sign in the equation 
$$ U=-\frac{GMm}{r}, $$
is absolutely essential.

First, its presence is due to the fact that $U$ comes from integration of the equation for $\vec{F}$, where the sign indicated that gravitational forces are attractive. Second, the minus sign shows that as $r$ becomes small, $U(r)$ becomes a large negative number. As $r$ goes to infinity, $U(r)$ goes to zero. Thus, the potential energy *does* increase as objects are moved far apart.

A good exercise is to derive $\Delta U = mg\Delta h$ using the formula for $U(r)$. As an immediate corollary, one also discoveres how $g$ is related to $G$, $M$, and $r_\text{earth}$.

Comment: "As r goes to infinity, U(r) goes to zero. Thus, the potential energy does increase as objects are moved far apart."
Hmm. So that kind of makes sense, but it seems bizarre to have the maximum PE occur at ~0. Any intuition you can give on why this is done?

Comment: At the level of this discussion, the fact that the maximum is 0 is just an arbitrary -- albeit reasonable -- choice. What's physical and important is the *change* in potential when moving from one point to another.